# Using Task and Async together for Asynchronous operations on seperate threads in F#

Tags: f#, f#-async

I'm being a little adventurous with my code for the amount of experience I have with F# and I am a little worried about cross threading issues.

**Background**:

I have a number of orders where I need to validate the address.  Some of the orders can be validated against google maps geocoding API which allows 50/ second. the rest are Australian PO Boxes which we don't have many of - but I need to validate them against a different API that only allows 1 call per second.

I have switched over most of my code from async{} functions to task{} functions and I am assuming to get something on several threads at the same time it needs to be in an async{} function or block and be piped to Async.Parallel

**Question**:  Is this the right way to do this or will it fall over? I am wondering if I am fundamentally thinking about this the wrong way.

Notes:

- I am passing a database context into the async function and updating the database within that function
- I will call this from a C# ( WPF ) Application and report the progress

Am I going to have cross threading issues?

```
let validateOrder
        (
            order: artooProvider.dataContext.``dbo.OrdersEntity``,
            httpClient: HttpClient,
            ctx: artooProvider.dataContext,
            isAuPoBox: bool
        ) =
        async {

            // Validate Address
            let! addressExceptions = ValidateAddress.validateAddress (order, httpClient, ctx, isAuPoBox) |> Async.AwaitTask

            // SaveExceptions
            do! ctx.SubmitUpdatesAsync()

            // return Exception count
            return ""
        }

    let validateGMapOrders(httpClient: HttpClient, ctx: artooProvider.dataContext, orders: artooProvider.dataContext.``dbo.OrdersEntity`` list) =
    async {
            let ordersChunked = orders |> List.chunkBySize 50

            for fiftyOrders in ordersChunked do
                let! tasks = 
                    fiftyOrders 
                    |> List.map (fun (order) -> validateOrder (order, httpClient, ctx, false) )
                    |> Async.Parallel
                do! Async.Sleep(2000)
        }


    let validateOrders (ctx: artooProvider.dataContext, progress: IProgress<DownloadProgressModel>) =
    task {
        let unvalidatedOrders =
            query {
                for orders in ctx.Dbo.Orders do
                    where (orders.IsValidated.IsNone)
                    select (orders)
            }
            |> Seq.toList

        let auPoBoxOrders =
            unvalidatedOrders
            |> List.filter (fun order -> isAUPoBox(order) = true )

        let gMapOrders =
            unvalidatedOrders
            |> List.filter (fun order -> isAUPoBox(order) = false )


        let googleHttpClient = new HttpClient()
        let auspostHttpclient = Auspost.AuspostApi.getApiClient ()

        // Google maps validations
        do! validateGMapOrders(googleHttpClient,ctx,gMapOrders)

        // PO Box Validations
        for position in 0 .. auPoBoxOrders.Length - 1 do
            let! result = validateOrder (gMapOrders[position], auspostHttpclient, ctx, true)
            do! Task.Delay(1000)

        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When I have had to deal with rate-limited API problems I hide that API behind a [`MailboxProcessor`](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpmailboxprocessor-1.html) that maintains an internal time to comply with the rate limit but appears as a normal `async` API from the outside.

Since you have two API's with different rate limits I'd parameterise the time delay and processing action then create one object for each API.

```ml
open System

type Request = string
type Response = string

type RateLimitedProcessor() =
    // Initialise 1s in past so ready to start immediately.
    let mutable lastCall = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
    let mbox = new MailboxProcessor<Request * AsyncReplyChannel<Response>>((fun mbox ->
        let rec f () = 
            async {
                let! (req, reply) = mbox.Receive()
                let msSinceCall = (DateTime.Now - lastCall).Milliseconds
                // wait 1s between requests
                if msSinceCall < 1000 then
                    do! Async.Sleep (1000 - msSinceCall)

                lastCall <- DateTime.Now
                reply.Reply "Response"

                // Call self recursively to process the next incoming message
                return! f()
            }
        f()
        ))

    do mbox.Start()
    
    member __.Process(req:Request): Async<Response> =
        async {
            return! mbox.PostAndAsyncReply(fun reply -> req, reply)
            }

    interface IDisposable with
        member this.Dispose() = (mbox :> IDisposable).Dispose()
```

Comment: MailboxProcessor to the rescue again.